# Generate multiple checkboxes and evaluate them

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I have a table that displays every unapproved leave, it looks like this:

[image]

For each unapproved there will be a new row, so another checkbox, but the name of the checkbox will be the same or slightly different(`name="approve1"`). Personally I don't think that's good practice...

Also the evaluation isn't really good, because it has to go into the database.

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="" id="form">
                <h2><?php echo $title ?></h2>
                    <?php 
                        $page = date('F');
                        $page = lcfirst($page);
                        echo "<p><a href='$page.php'>Back</a></p>";
                    ?>
                    <hr>
                <?php



                if($i == 0){
                echo "<h3>No unapproved leaves.</h3>";
                }else{
                echo '<table class="table table-striped table-hover">';
                echo '<thead>';
                    echo '<th>';
                    echo 'Start';
                    echo '</th>';
                    echo '<th>';
                    echo 'End';
                    echo '</th>';
                    echo '<th>';
                    echo 'Employee';
                    echo '</th>';
                    echo '<th>';
                    echo 'Approve';
                    echo '</th>';
                echo '</thead>';
                echo '<tbody>';
                for($j =0; $j < $i; $j++){


                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>';
                    echo $unapproved[$j]['start'];
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                    echo $unapproved[$j]['end'];
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                    $id = $unapproved[$j]['employee_FK'];
                    $result = mysql_query("select name, surname from employee where employee_ID =  $id");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $employee[] = $row;
                    }
                    echo $employee[0]['name'], " ", $employee[0]['surname'];
                    echo '</td>';

                    echo '<td>';
                    echo  '<input type="checkbox" name="approve" value="1" id="approve">';
                    echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
                }
                echo '</tbody>';
                echo '</table>';
                }

                ?>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" >
            </div>

        </div>



    </form>
```

Can anyone think of a better, easier solution?

Comment: Show us your code :-) - [See this article on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For Loop might help you

Comment: Added the code but it's only made for a single checkbox(1 leave). @Ganesh Salunkhe I wanted to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practice for tabular data in most frameworks is to name them `Model[id][field]`, so in your example it would look like `"<input type='checkbox' name='leave[$j][approved]' value='1' id='leave_$j_approved'>"`.

Then you can easily access your data by iterating the post data like so:

```
foreach($_POST['leave'] as $id => $values) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use checkbox name like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="approve[]" value="<?php $your_row_id; ?>" id="approve">
```

here `$your_row_id` means unique id of a row in database.

And in post you will get an array named `approve` with all the selected values.

Parse that array using foreach.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer [arrays](http://php.net/arrays) via HTTP :

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="approve[]" value="', $id, ']" id="approve">';
```

Now `$_GET['approve']` will be an array which only contains values of checked boxes.

You can also specify the key associated with the value:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="approve[', $id, ']" value="', $id, ']" id="approve">';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate checkboxes using a array notation in the "`name`" attribute.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="approve[]" value="1" id="approve">
```

After on send, you can recover values using array notation `$_GET['approve'][0]`, ...

Comment: But I would have to set the method to get, right? This looks quite good.